# How to remove many append() <option> and <div> together?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a problem with my JQuery, I'm actually on a feature that I want to add.
I don't know how to remove a specific option from tag with a specific div together.

For example : when I create a book and name it "Book A" when I remove Book A with the button remove, then the Book A removed too.

And same if I create a book and name it "Book A" and a chapter in the Book A named Chap. And in the same example if i remove the book A, then the Book A and all chapters inside it  tag removed.

Here is my code :

```js
//Remove Buttons - Function ////START////
$("#list").on('click', "button.removeBook", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeChapter", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
//Remove Buttons - Function ////END////

//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////START////
$("#select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#select-choice > div").hide();
  $("." + val).slideToggle();
});
//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////END////

//Append generated elements- Function ////START////
//FOR BOOK
$('#createBook').click(function() {
  var listItem = $('#bookName').val();
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichBook">
  $("#whichBook").append('<option>' + $('#bookName').val() + '</option>');

  //Create a <div class="BookName"> in <div id="list">
  $('#list').append('<div class="BookName" data-book-name="' + $('#bookName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
  $('#bookName').val('');
});

//FOR CHAPTER
$('#createChapter').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichChapter"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist
  if ($('.BookName').length > 0) {
    $("#whichChapter").append('<option>' + $('#chapterName').val() + '</option>');
    var listItem = $('#chapterName').val();
    var bookName = $('#whichBook option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");

    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.
    $('.BookName[data-book-name=' + bookName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName" data-chapter-name="' + $('#chapterName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});
//Append generated elements- Function ////END////
```

```css
#select-choice>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="none">Select something</option>
  <option value="book">a Book</option>
  <option value="chapter">a Chapter</option>
</select>

<div id="select-choice">
  <div class="book">
    <input type="text" id="bookName" name="name" placeholder="Book Name">
    <button type="button" name="createBook" id="createBook">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <select id="whichBook">
      <option value="none">From which book?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="chapterName" name="name" placeholder="Chapter Name">
    <button type="button" name="createChapter" id="createChapter">Créer le site</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function to your Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function(){
    var bookName = $(this).closest('.BookName' ).attr('data-book-name');
    $('#whichBook option:contains('+ bookName +')').remove();
});
```

```js
//Remove Buttons - Function ////START////
$("#list").on('click', "button.removeBook", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeChapter", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
//Remove Buttons - Function ////END////

//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////START////
$("#select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#select-choice > div").hide();
  $("." + val).slideToggle();
});
//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////END////

//Append generated elements- Function ////START////
//FOR BOOK
$('#createBook').click(function() {
  var listItem = $('#bookName').val();
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichBook">
  $("#whichBook").append('<option>' + $('#bookName').val() + '</option>');

  //Create a <div class="BookName"> in <div id="list">
  $('#list').append('<div class="BookName" data-book-name="' + $('#bookName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
  $('#bookName').val('');
});

//FOR CHAPTER
$('#createChapter').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichChapter"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist
  if ($('.BookName').length > 0) {
    $("#whichChapter").append('<option>' + $('#chapterName').val() + '</option>');
    var listItem = $('#chapterName').val();
    var bookName = $('#whichBook option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");

    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.
    $('.BookName[data-book-name=' + bookName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName" data-chapter-name="' + $('#chapterName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function(){
  var bookName = $(this).closest('.BookName' ).attr('data-book-name');
  $('#whichBook option:contains('+ bookName +')').remove();
});
//Append generated elements- Function ////END////
```

```css
#select-choice>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="none">Select something</option>
  <option value="book">a Book</option>
  <option value="chapter">a Chapter</option>
</select>

<div id="select-choice">
  <div class="book">
    <input type="text" id="bookName" name="name" placeholder="Book Name">
    <button type="button" name="createBook" id="createBook">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <select id="whichBook">
      <option value="none">From which book?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="chapterName" name="name" placeholder="Chapter Name">
    <button type="button" name="createChapter" id="createChapter">Créer le site</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add data-bookId attribute while adding option to a book dropdown and options of a chapter dropdown.

In Jquery, you can simply remove all options with data-bookId like:

```
 $('option[data-bookId="SomeId"]').remove();
```

This will remove all the options with this attribute from both dropdowns. Make sure, Book Id should be unique for each book. Hope it helps :)

```js
function removeBook()
{
    $('option[data-bookId="' + $('#bookDropdown option:selected').attr("data-bookId")  + '"]').remove();
}
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select id="bookDropdown">
    <option>Select Book</option>
    <option data-bookId="English">English</option>
    <option data-bookId="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option data-bookId="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option data-bookId="Biology">Biology</option>
    <option data-bookId="French Language">French Language</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<select id="chapsDropdown">
    <option>Select Chapter</option>
    <option data-bookId="English">Grammer</option>
    <option data-bookId="English">Stories</option>
    <option data-bookId="English">Letters</option>
    <option data-bookId="Mathematics">Algebra</option>
    <option data-bookId="Mathematics">Limits</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<button onclick="removeBook()">Remove Book</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MuhalladQasim ! I will try to put this data attribute.
And in your example, it's mostly a pre-generated content, do you know how i could update the data-bookId value each time i create a book, and always attribute the chapter with the right data-bookId for exemple if the value is 2 because i create 2 books return to the value 1 to put inside the first book ?

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use the name of the book in data-bookId attribute but then you will have to check whenever you are going to add a book, its name should not exist in existing options of dorpdown

Comment: Also, when adding a chapter, show that bookdropdown to user to select the book against he is trying to add a chapter. And then you can get the data-bookId attribute from selected option of bookdropdown to set in newly added options